# Помогите разобраться с DataFrame на питоне

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

В меня есть набор данных, где хранятся данные мужчин и женщин. В задаче не было дано, какое описание признака пола соответствует gender=1 и gender=2. Пол можно определить по параметру роста, по разумным меркам мужчины всегда выше женщин.

Моё решение этой проблемы:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mlbootcamp5_train.csv',sep=';',index_col='id')
print('Інформація для пяти перших користувачів: ')
print(df[['age', 'gender', 'height']].head())

mean1 = df.loc[df['gender']==1, 'height'].mean()
print("Середній зріст осіб за першою гендерною ознакою: {0:.2f}".format(mean1))
mean2 = df.loc[df['gender']==2, 'height'].mean()
print("Середній зріст осіб за другою гендерною ознакою: {0:.2f}".format(mean2))

print('Кількість всіх осіб: ', len(df))
print('Кількість осіб за першою гендерною ознакою: ', len(df.loc[df['gender']==1]))
print('Кількість осіб за другою гендерною ознакою: ', len(df.loc[df['gender']==2]))

max_height = df.loc[df['gender']==1, 'height'].max()
print('Найвижчий зріст для першої гендерної ознаки: ', max_height)
min_height = df.loc[df['gender']==1, 'height'].min()
print('Найменший зріст для першої гендерної ознаки: ', min_height)

max_height2 = df.loc[df['gender']==2, 'height'].max()
print('Найвижчий зріст для другої гендерної ознаки: ', max_height2)
min_height2 = df.loc[df['gender']==2, 'height'].min()
print('Найменший зріст для другої генедерної ознаки: ', min_height2)
```

Мне кажется, что я неправильно определил максимальный и минимальный рост для каждого пола. По результатам вышло, что 1 - женщины, а 2 - мужчины. Не знаю насколько в меня правильное решение, можно ли как-то по другому это решить?

Comment: Почему вам кажется, что вы неправильно определили? Какие у вас получились значения min/max и mean по одному полу и по другому? В данных могут быть выбросы, поэтому надо всегда смотреть разную статистику. (Из-за выбросов может оказаться, что максимум больше у одного пола, а среднее - у другого.) Хорошо бы посмотреть для контроля медиану. А так с виду у вас всё нормально, хоть и сильно не оптимально, можно зарефакторить более коротко.

Comment: И вообще посмотрите например так `df.loc[df['gender']==1, ['age', 'gender', 'height']].describe()` - там будет сразу вся статистика по трём колонкам, из неё можно будет сделать какие-то выводы наверняка. Считать вручную ничего не надо, в `Pandas` уже всё есть.

Comment: Я проверял на тестовых данных, всё правильно у меня. Спасибо за помощь. Я недавно начал изучать Python. Можете какие-то книги новые посоветовать? Про библиотеки matplotlib, sklearn, scipy, pandas.

Comment: Обычно достаточно чтения официальной документации, там и примеры есть как использовать конкретные функции. Но если будет совсем непонятно, на youtube есть полно обучающих видео для начинающих, тоже бывает полезно посмотреть, послушать.